# How to change the global background color in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am using Bash on [WebFaction](https://www.webfaction.com/faq/) (web hosting) and would like to change my terminal to default to a different background color than black (probably white, but I'd like to play around with it).  How do I do this?

I tried doing this:

```
cp /etc/DIR_COLORS ~/.dir_colors
(edit .dir_colors)
```

But I could only find the foreground and background colors for various directories and file types, not a global one.  Where should I look?

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place.  This is a function of your terminal emulator, NOT bash or dircolors.

Comment: yes, that worked, changed the putty settings, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you don't have to do it with Bash. Check your terminal emulator display properties.

*Note*: The shell (Bash in your case) can change the text and background color, but the property can be lost or changed by further ANSI color codes invocations.

Comment: This does not answer the question.